# UPDATE in combination with nested SELECT queries and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, select, update

I have a problem with an UPDATE statement that contains a nested SELECT statement in combination with LEFT OUTER JOIN statements.

Situation: In our database there is a new column added to all people who are in our database, and I want to update the column with the value "X" on certain people, but only to the people that have certain conditions.

With the following SELECT statement I successfully select all people that need to have this column updated. The column that I want to update is " Testfield"

```
SELECT
    TESTDB.CONTACT.number2 AS CustomerID,
    TESTDB.PERSON.firstname AS FirstName,
    TESTDB.PERSON.lastname AS LastName,
    (SELECT UPPER(string19) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) AS Testfield
FROM         
    TESTDB.CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.PERSON ON TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL ON TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.udpersonSmall_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE ON TESTDB.CONTACT.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE.udcontactLarge_id
WHERE 
    (TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id) 
/*  No retired people*/
    AND TESTDB.PERSON.retired = '0'
/*  Other conditions*/
    AND ((SELECT UPPER(string05) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'A'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string07) FROM CRM5.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'B'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string08) FROM CRM5.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'C')
/*  testpersonen*/
    AND (SELECT string45 FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE.UDPERSONLARGE_id) = '123'
ORDER BY
    CustomerID, FirstName, LastName
```

Output:

```
10001;Test1;Person1;
10001;Test2;Person2;
10001;Test3;Person3;
10001;Test4;Person4;
10001;Test6;Person6;
10001;Test7;Person7;
10001;Test8;Person8;

(7 rows affected)
```

This is correct, the people have the value NULL on the Testfield at the moment. (the fourth column is empty)

Now I want to update the column "Testfield", and tried this so far:

```
UPDATE
    TESTDB.CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.PERSON ON TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL ON TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.udpersonSmall_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE ON TESTDB.CONTACT.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE.udcontactLarge_id
SET
    (SELECT UPPER(string19) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'J'
WHERE 
    (TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id) 
/*  No retired people*/
    AND TESTDB.PERSON.retired = '0'
/*  Other conditions*/
    AND ((SELECT UPPER(string05) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'A'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string07) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'B'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string08) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'C')
/*  testpersonen*/
    AND (SELECT string45 FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE.UDPERSONLARGE_id) = '123'
```

But here I get the error that it doesn't accept the LEFT OUTER JOIN placed here:

> `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 3` 
>     `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.`
>     `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 7`
>     `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 7`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 15`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 16`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 17`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 19`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

I also tried it like this:

```
UPDATE
    TESTDB
SET
    (SELECT UPPER(string19) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'X'
FROM
    TESTDB.CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.PERSON ON TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL ON TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.udpersonSmall_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE ON TESTDB.CONTACT.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE.udcontactLarge_id
WHERE 
    (TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id) 
/*  No retired people*/
    AND TESTDB.PERSON.retired = '0'
/*  Other conditions*/
    AND ((SELECT UPPER(string05) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'X'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string07) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'X'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string08) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'X')
/*  testpersonen*/
    AND (SELECT string45 FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE.UDPERSONLARGE_id) = '123'
```

This results in another error:

> `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 4`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '('.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 4`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 17`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 18`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 19`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`
>     `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TESTSERVER, Line 21`
>     `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

The software is a CRM with a SQL Server 2005 database.

Could someone help me with the syntax? I'm getting lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, note that you can't `SET` the result of a SELECT statement to a value; you have to set a specific column to the value you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SELECT` query can be simplified quite a bit, which would make it easier to figure out what UPDATE statement is needed. All of those `SELECT UPPER` are unnecessary as you've already joined to them, so just reference the column.

Try this in a test environment:

```
UPDATE c
SET TestField = UPPER(udps.string19)
FROM         
    TESTDB.CONTACT c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.PERSON p ON c.contact_id = p.contact_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL udps ON p.userdef_id = udps.udpersonSmall_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE udc ON c.userdef2_id = udc.udcontactLarge_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE udpl ON p.userdef2_id = udpl.UDPERSONLARGE_id
WHERE 
/*  No retired people*/
    p.retired = '0'
/*  Other conditions*/
    AND (UPPER(udps.string05) = 'A'
    OR   UPPER(udps.string07) = 'B'
    OR   UPPER(udps.string08) = 'C')
/*  testpersonen*/
    AND udpl.string45 = '123'
```

Comment: Thanks, only one thing, how can I put value "J" into TestField now as you seem to use the SET clause to compare TestField with UPPER(udps.string19), instead of putting the value 'J' in TestField (which is UPPER(udps.string19)) ?

Comment: Ok, I changed "TestField = UPPER(udps.string19)" to "udps.string19 = 'J'" now. I'm going to try it in a minute.

Comment: It worked with a small edit!

I changed the top 2 lines to:

UPDATE udps
SET udps.string19 = 'J'

That did it. Thanks for your help, really cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps:

```
Update TESTDB.CONTACT 
SET Testfield = SubTestField
FROM
(
SELECT
    TESTDB.CONTACT.number2 AS CustomerID,
    TESTDB.PERSON.firstname AS FirstName,
    TESTDB.PERSON.lastname AS LastName,
    TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id AS SubContact_ID
    (SELECT UPPER(string19) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) AS SubTestfield
FROM         
    TESTDB.CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.PERSON ON TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL ON TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.udpersonSmall_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE ON TESTDB.CONTACT.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDCONTACTLARGE.udcontactLarge_id
WHERE 
    (TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = TESTDB.PERSON.contact_id) 
/*  No retired people*/
    AND TESTDB.PERSON.retired = '0'
/*  Other conditions*/
    AND (
    (SELECT UPPER(string05) FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'A'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string07) FROM CRM5.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'B'
    OR  (SELECT UPPER(string08) FROM CRM5.UDPERSONSMALL WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONSMALL.UDPERSONSMALL_id) = 'C'
    )
/*  testpersonen*/
    AND (SELECT string45 FROM TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE WHERE TESTDB.PERSON.userdef2_id = TESTDB.UDPERSONLARGE.UDPERSONLARGE_id) = '123'
    )Sub
Where TESTDB.CONTACT.contact_id = SubContact_ID
```

Your set clause needs to have a value to compare to. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/5149122) by [Robin Day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40655/robin-day) for another example. I will also post the example below for viewing ease.

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```